# Log in on Facebook: app is misconfigured

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to write an application that can log in facebook. I use easyfacebooksdk.jar like library to use your API, but I have problem with configuration. I post the follow image:
This is the facebook app that I have created:

[image]

I have obtained the key hash in this way from console:

[image]

I put this code here in key has field( i can't post the image because i don't have 10 reputation)

**This is my code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity   implements LoginListener {

    private FBLoginManager fbManager;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            shareFacebook();
    }


    public void shareFacebook() {

    //change the permissions according to the function you want to use 
            String permissions[] = { "read_stream", "user_relationship_details",
                            "user_religion_politics", "user_work_history",
                            "user_relationships", "user_interests", "user_likes",
                            "user_location", "user_hometown", "user_education_history",
                            "user_activities", "offline_access" };

            //change the parameters with those of your application
            fbManager = new FBLoginManager(this, R.layout.activity_main,
                            "334014040053829", permissions);


            if (fbManager.existsSavedFacebook()) {
                    fbManager.loadFacebook();
            } else {

                    fbManager.login();
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            fbManager.loginSuccess(data);
    }

    public void loginFail() {
            fbManager.displayToast("Login failed!");

    }

    public void logoutSuccess() {
            fbManager.displayToast("Logout success!");
    }

    public void loginSuccess(Facebook facebook) {

            //library use example
            GraphApi graphApi = new GraphApi(facebook);

            User user = new User();
            try {
                    user = graphApi.getMyAccountInfo();
                    graphApi.setStatus("Post by app");
            } catch (EasyFacebookError e) {
                    e.toString();
            }




    }
}
```

I obtain this error in emulator: app is misconfigured to facebook log in but i don't understand why... Someone can you help me?

Comment: have you added key in code ?

Comment: One question for the OP that is absolutely unrelated to the issue at hand. Why would you use an **unofficial SDK** that was last updated on [**06/11/2011**](http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/download.asp)? Wouldn't the official Facebook SDK be a better alternative if you are just getting started with the app?

Comment: sorry I forget my code now I modified my post:

Comment: @IceMan i try to follow these guide but at the step 4 when I must load ProfilePictureSample( i don't remember its name but it's in example) I obtain the NoClassFoundException...really I don't know